# How to solve an error on django admin interface

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

[dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p8vyY.png)[my django dshboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MAFkN.png)Hi i am using Django admin to work on some task. i have created a model and added project name. so whenever i am creating a project say 'project5' and adding details and if again i am creating another project with same name and same details it is being created. What i want is i do not want the project name created to be with same details. it should give error. Please let me know how to fix this.

Here below i have created a model with a class name and some fields.
i have sorted it with unique=True

Also  i have created different users who can further create project name. if user1 has created project1, I also want user2 to create project1. i mean same user cannot create project with same name but different users can create project with same name.Please let me know how to fix this enter image description here.

Modals.py

```
class Project(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    added_by = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (("name", "users"))
```

Settings.py

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.User'
```

admin.py

```
list_display = ['name', 'created_at', 'added_by']
    inlines = [JiraDetailsInline, ZephyrDetailsInline]
    exclude = ['added_by']

    def get_actions(self, request):
        return None

    def get_model_perms(self, request):
         
        if request.user and request.user.is_authenticated and request.user.is_superuser:
            return {}
        return super().get_model_perms(request)

    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        """
        Return form with removing added_by field if user is not superuser
        """
        self.exclude = []
        if not request.user.is_superuser:
            self.exclude.append('added_by')  # here!
        return super(ProjectAdmin, self).get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        """
        Method to save current logged in user in added by field.
        """
        if not obj.added_by:
            # Only set added_by during the first save.
            obj.added_by = request.user
        super().save_model(request, obj, form, change)

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        """Make a queryset for list of results.

        Parameters
        ----------
        request : object
            Current request

        Returns
        ------
        Queryset
            List of users that is created by current owner.
        """
        qs = super().get_queryset(request)
        if request.user.is_superuser:
            return qs
        if request.user.is_client_user():
            return qs.filter(added_by=request.user.client.created_by)
        return qs.filter(added_by=request.user)


class DuplicateTestCaseAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    
    list_display = ['test_case_id', 'dup_test_case_id', 'created_at']

    class Media:
       
        css = {
            'all': ('//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css', 'css/test_suite_optimizer.css')
        }
        js = (
            '/admin/jsi18n/',
            '//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js',
            '//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js',
            'js/test_suite_optimizer.js',
        )

    def get_urls(self):
        urls = super().get_urls()
        my_urls = [
            path('upload_csv/', self.admin_site.admin_view(self.process_csv)),
            path('<slug:project>/results/',
                 self.admin_site.admin_view(self.show_ai_result)),
        ]
        return my_urls + urls

    def process_csv(self, request):
        data = [
            ["TC-16610", "V2-8794: verify that user is able to update 'active' attribute  'false ' on adding new category records using 'v3/definition/categories' PUT API on specifying the 'active' attribute 'true'", [["TC-16609", "V2-8794: verify that user is able to update 'active' attribute  'true ' on adding new category records using 'v3/definition/categories' PUT API on specifying the 'active' attribute 'false'", "Highly Similar"], ["TC-16609", "V2-8794: verify that user is able to update 'active' attribute  'true ' on adding new category records using 'v3/definition/categories' PUT API on specifying the 'active' attribute 'false'", "Highly Similar"]]
             ],
            ["TC-16610", "V2-8794: verify that user is able to update 'active' attribute  'false ' on adding new category records using 'v3/definition/categories' PUT API on specifying the 'active' attribute 'true'", [["TC-16609", "V2-8794: verify that user is able to update 'active' attribute  'true ' on adding new category records using 'v3/definition/categories' PUT API on specifying the 'active' attribute 'false'", "Highly Similar"], ["TC-16609", "V2-8794: verify that user is able to update 'active' attribute  'true ' on adding new category records using 'v3/definition/categories' PUT API on specifying the 'active' attribute 'false'", "Highly Similar"], ["TC-16609", "V2-8794: verify that user is able to update 'active' attribute  'true ' on adding new category records using 'v3/definition/categories' PUT API on specifying the 'active' attribute 'false'", "Highly Similar"]]
             ],
            ["TC-16610", "V2-8794: verify that user is able to update 'active' attribute  'false ' on adding new category records using 'v3/definition/categories' PUT API on specifying the 'active' attribute 'true'", [["TC-16609", "V2-8794: verify that user is able to update 'active' attribute  'true ' on adding new category records using 'v3/definition/categories' PUT API on specifying the 'active' attribute 'false'", "Highly Similar"]]
             ]
        ]
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = CsvUpload(request.POST, request.FILES)

            # check whether it's valid:
            if form.is_valid():
                # process the data in form.cleaned_data as required
                # ...
                # redirect to a new URL:
                csv_data = form.cleaned_data.get('csv_file')
                data = handle_demo_ai(csv_data)
                context = {
                    "invoice_id": 123,
                    "customer_name": "John Cooper",
                    "amount": 1399.99,
                    "today": "Today",
                    "data": data

                }
                # print(csv_data)
                # html = template.render(context)
                pdf = render_to_pdf('pdf/duplicate_defects_org.html', context)
                # pdf = render_to_pdf('pdf/duplicate_defects.html', context)
                # print(pdf)
                if pdf:
                    response = HttpResponse(
                        pdf, content_type='application/pdf')
                    filename = "Invoice_%s.pdf" % ("12341231")
                    filename = "output.pdf"
                    content = "inline; filename='%s'" % (filename)
                    download = request.GET.get("download")
                    if download:
                        content = "attachment; filename=%s" % (filename)
                    response['Content-Disposition'] = content
                    return response
                # return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/')
        else:
            form = CsvUpload()
        context = dict(
            # Include common variables for rendering the admin template.
            self.admin_site.each_context(request),
            # Anything else you want in the context...
            title="Process CSV",
            form=form,
            data=data
        )
        # return TemplateResponse(request, "pdf/duplicate_defects_org.html", context)
        return TemplateResponse(request, "admin/test_suite_optimizer/duplicatetestcase/process_csv/sometemplate.html", context)

    def show_ai_result(self, request, project=None):
        try:
            page = int(request.GET.get('page', 1))
        except Exception as e:
            page = 1
        project = get_object_or_404(Project,
                                    pk=project)
        file = get_ai_result_file_name(
            settings.BASE_DIR, request.user.id, project.id)
        try:
            pickle_off = open(file, "rb")
        except Exception as e:
            return HttpResponseNotFound()
        data = pickle.load(pickle_off)
        paginator = Paginator(data, AI_RESULT_PAGE_SIZE)
        page_obj = paginator.get_page(page)
        # pages = int(ceil(len(data)/ AI_RESULT_PAGE_SIZE))
        # if page > pages:
        #     return HttpResponseNotFound()
        # start = (page-1)*AI_RESULT_PAGE_SIZE
        # end = start+AI_RESULT_PAGE_SIZE
        # data = data[start:end]

        context = dict(
            # Include common variables for rendering the admin template.
            self.admin_site.each_context(request),
            # Anything else you want in the context...
            title="Results",
            project=project.id,
            page_obj=page_obj,
            page=page,
        )
        # return TemplateResponse(request, "pdf/duplicate_defects_org.html", context)
        return TemplateResponse(request, "admin/test_suite_optimizer/duplicatetestcase/full_suite_optimize_result.html", context)

    def has_add_permission(self, request):
        return False

    def get_model_perms(self, request):
        """
        Return empty perms dict thus hiding the model from admin index.
        """
        if request.user and request.user.is_authenticated and request.user.is_superuser:
            return {}
        return super().get_model_perms(request)

    def changelist_view_(self, request, extra_context=None):
        extra_context = extra_context or {}
        extra_context['some_var'] = 'This is what I want to show'
        return super(DuplicateTestCaseAdmin, self).changelist_view(request, extra_context=extra_context)

    def changelist_view(self, request, extra_context=None):
        """Get test cases from jira and pass them to AI and then Show AI output.
        Return
        --------
            Change list view
        """
        extra_context = extra_context or {}
        # jira_data = []
        try:
            p = int(request.GET.get('p', 1))
        except Exception as e:
            p = 1
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = AIAnalyzeForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                project = get_object_or_404(Project,
                                            pk=request.POST.get('project'))
                correct_jira_cred = False
                try:
                    jira = Jira(project.jiraapi.project_key, project.jiraapi.email,
                                project.jiraapi.api_token, project.jiraapi.jira_subdomain)
                    jira_data = jira.get_test_cases()
                    correct_jira_cred = True
                except Exception as e:
                    correct_jira_cred = False
                    messages.error(request, _(
                        "Please enter correct jira credentials for this project."))
                if correct_jira_cred:
                    duplicated_data = jira.get_test_cases_marked_as_duplicates()
                    filtered_jira_data = [
                        i for i in jira_data + duplicated_data if i not in jira_data or i not in duplicated_data]
                    extra_context['show_ai_result'] = True
                    threshold = form.cleaned_data.get('threshold')
                    # filtered_jira_data.reverse()
                    # # print(jira_data)
                    # import copy
                    # copy.copy(x)
                    # copy.deepcopy(x)
                    ai_result = handle_json_ai_up(json.dumps(
                        filtered_jira_data), threshold.max, threshold.min)
                    folder = '%s/ai_models/user_%s/ai_results' % (
                        settings.BASE_DIR, request.user.id)
                    if not os.path.exists(folder):
                        os.makedirs(folder)
                    file = get_ai_result_file_name(
                        settings.BASE_DIR, request.user.id, project.id)

                    # print(file)
                    with open(file, 'wb') as fh:
                        pickle.dump(ai_result, fh)
                    # pages = int(ceil(len(ai_result)/ AI_RESULT_PAGE_SIZE))
                    # start =  0
                    # end = AI_RESULT_PAGE_SIZE
                    # find_file = "%s/ai_models/user_%s/datafile_%s*" % (settings.BASE_DIR, request.user.id, project.id)
                    # for filename in glob.glob(find_file):
                    #     os.remove(filename)
                    # for page in range(1, pages+1):
                    #     page_data = ai_result[start:end]
                    #     start += AI_RESULT_PAGE_SIZE
                    #     end += AI_RESULT_PAGE_SIZE
                    #     file = '%s/ai_models/user_%s/datafile_%s.txt' % (
                    #         settings.BASE_DIR, request.user.id, project.id, page)
                    #     # print(file)
                    #     with open(file, 'wb') as fh:
                    #        pickle.dump(page_data, fh)
                    # print(ai_result[1: AI_RESULT_PAGE_SIZE+1])
                    # import os, glob

                    # print(ai_result)

                    # ai_result = handle_json_ai(json.dumps(filtered_jira_data), threshold.max, threshold.min)
                    return HttpResponseRedirect("%s/results/" % project.id)
                    translations = {
                        'sno': _('Sno.'),
                        # 'thres_score': _('Threshold score'),
                        'test_case_id': _('Test case id'),
                        'test_case_summary': _('Test case summary'),
                        'dup_test_case_ids': _('Duplicate test case id\'s'),
                        'action': _('Action'),
                        'action': _('Done'),
                    }
                    extra_context['json_data'] = ai_result
                    extra_context['translations'] = translations
                    extra_context['project'] = project.id
                    return super(DuplicateTestCaseAdmin, self).changelist_view(
                        request, extra_context=extra_context,
                    )
        form = AIAnalyzeForm()
        if request.user.is_superuser:
            projects = Project.objects.all()
        elif request.user.is_client_user():
            projects = Project.objects.filter(
                added_by=request.user.client.created_by)
        else:
            projects = Project.objects.filter(added_by=request.user)
        paginator = Paginator(projects, 20)
        page_obj = paginator.get_page(p)
        extra_context['form'] = form
        extra_context['projects'] = page_obj
        extra_context['paginator'] = page_obj
        return super(DuplicateTestCaseAdmin, self).changelist_view(request, extra_context=extra_context)


admin.site.register(Project, ProjectAdmin)
admin.site.register(DuplicateTestCase, DuplicateTestCaseAdmin)
admin.site.unregister(Task)
admin.site.unregister(CompletedTask)
```

Comment: Show me your code please!

Comment: Posted the code above. and unique_togetherness gives an error.'unique_together' refers to the nonexistent field 'users'.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is [unique_together](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/options/#unique-together).

If you want your Project model to have unique names, but per user,
you will need something a bit like this:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField("Name", max_length=200)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    
    class Meta:
        unique_together = (("name", "user"),)
```

Comment: Hi sir , i have posted the code above and unique_togetherness gives an error.'unique_together' refers to the nonexistent field 'users'.

Comment: Make sure it's user and not users if you're variable name is user

Answer (score 0):

Please refer this [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#unique) for understand unique. You have no field `users` in your code. I conside `users` field as `added_by` then, please change `added_by` to `users`. Not give non existing field as unique property.

**1st method**

Here we using `unique_together`.

```
class Project(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    users = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (("name", "users"))
```

**2nd method**

Here we using `unique=True` as separated fields.

```
 class Project(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=200,unique=True)
        users = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True, default=None,unique=True)
        created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
        updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

**admin.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
class ProjectAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['name', 'created_at', 'users']
    inlines = [JiraDetailsInline, ZephyrDetailsInline]
    exclude = ['users']

    def get_actions(self, request):
        return None

    def get_model_perms(self, request):
         
        if request.user and request.user.is_authenticated and request.user.is_superuser:
            return {}
        return super().get_model_perms(request)

    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):

        self.exclude = []
        if not request.user.is_superuser:
            self.exclude.append('users')  # here!
        return super(ProjectAdmin, self).get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        """
        Method to save current logged in user in added by field.
        """
        if not obj.users:
            # Only set users during the first save.
            obj.users = request.user
        super().save_model(request, obj, form, change)

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super().get_queryset(request)
        if request.user.is_superuser:
            return qs
        if request.user.is_client_user():
            return qs.filter(users=request.user.client.created_by)
        return qs.filter(users=request.user)


class DuplicateTestCaseAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    list_display = ['test_case_id', 'dup_test_case_id', 'created_at']

    class Media:
       
        css = {
            'all': ('//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css', 'css/test_suite_optimizer.css')
        }
        js = (
            '/admin/jsi18n/',
            '//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js',
            '//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js',
            'js/test_suite_optimizer.js',
        )

    def get_urls(self):
        urls = super().get_urls()
        my_urls = [
            path('upload_csv/', self.admin_site.admin_view(self.process_csv)),
            path('<slug:project>/results/',
                 self.admin_site.admin_view(self.show_ai_result)),
        ]
        return my_urls + urls

    def process_csv(self, request):
        data = [
            ["TC-16610", "V2-8794: verify that user is able to update 'active' attribute  'false ' on adding new category records using 'v3/definition/categories' PUT API on specifying the 'active' attribute 'true'", [["TC-16609", "V2-8794: verify that user is able to update 'active' attribute  'true ' on adding new category records using 'v3/definition/categories' PUT API on specifying the 'active' attribute 'false'", "Highly Similar"], ["TC-16609", "V2-8794: verify that user is able to update 'active' attribute  'true ' on adding new category records using 'v3/definition/categories' PUT API on specifying the 'active' attribute 'false'", "Highly Similar"]]
             ],
            ["TC-16610", "V2-8794: verify that user is able to update 'active' attribute  'false ' on adding new category records using 'v3/definition/categories' PUT API on specifying the 'active' attribute 'true'", [["TC-16609", "V2-8794: verify that user is able to update 'active' attribute  'true ' on adding new category records using 'v3/definition/categories' PUT API on specifying the 'active' attribute 'false'", "Highly Similar"], ["TC-16609", "V2-8794: verify that user is able to update 'active' attribute  'true ' on adding new category records using 'v3/definition/categories' PUT API on specifying the 'active' attribute 'false'", "Highly Similar"], ["TC-16609", "V2-8794: verify that user is able to update 'active' attribute  'true ' on adding new category records using 'v3/definition/categories' PUT API on specifying the 'active' attribute 'false'", "Highly Similar"]]
             ],
            ["TC-16610", "V2-8794: verify that user is able to update 'active' attribute  'false ' on adding new category records using 'v3/definition/categories' PUT API on specifying the 'active' attribute 'true'", [["TC-16609", "V2-8794: verify that user is able to update 'active' attribute  'true ' on adding new category records using 'v3/definition/categories' PUT API on specifying the 'active' attribute 'false'", "Highly Similar"]]
             ]
        ]
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = CsvUpload(request.POST, request.FILES)

            if form.is_valid():

                csv_data = form.cleaned_data.get('csv_file')
                data = handle_demo_ai(csv_data)
                context = {
                    "invoice_id": 123,
                    "customer_name": "John Cooper",
                    "amount": 1399.99,
                    "today": "Today",
                    "data": data

                }
                pdf = render_to_pdf('pdf/duplicate_defects_org.html', context)

                if pdf:
                    response = HttpResponse(
                        pdf, content_type='application/pdf')
                    filename = "Invoice_%s.pdf" % ("12341231")
                    filename = "output.pdf"
                    content = "inline; filename='%s'" % (filename)
                    download = request.GET.get("download")
                    if download:
                        content = "attachment; filename=%s" % (filename)
                    response['Content-Disposition'] = content
                    return response
                # return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/')
        else:
            form = CsvUpload()
        context = dict(
            # Include common variables for rendering the admin template.
            self.admin_site.each_context(request),
            # Anything else you want in the context...
            title="Process CSV",
            form=form,
            data=data
        )
        return TemplateResponse(request, "admin/test_suite_optimizer/duplicatetestcase/process_csv/sometemplate.html", context)

    def show_ai_result(self, request, project=None):
        try:
            page = int(request.GET.get('page', 1))
        except Exception as e:
            page = 1
        project = get_object_or_404(Project,
                                    pk=project)
        file = get_ai_result_file_name(
            settings.BASE_DIR, request.user.id, project.id)
        try:
            pickle_off = open(file, "rb")
        except Exception as e:
            return HttpResponseNotFound()
        data = pickle.load(pickle_off)
        paginator = Paginator(data, AI_RESULT_PAGE_SIZE)
        page_obj = paginator.get_page(page)

        context = dict(
            # Include common variables for rendering the admin template.
            self.admin_site.each_context(request),
            # Anything else you want in the context...
            title="Results",
            project=project.id,
            page_obj=page_obj,
            page=page,
        )
        return TemplateResponse(request, "admin/test_suite_optimizer/duplicatetestcase/full_suite_optimize_result.html", context)

    def has_add_permission(self, request):
        return False

    def get_model_perms(self, request):
        """
        Return empty perms dict thus hiding the model from admin index.
        """
        if request.user and request.user.is_authenticated and request.user.is_superuser:
            return {}
        return super().get_model_perms(request)

    def changelist_view_(self, request, extra_context=None):
        extra_context = extra_context or {}
        extra_context['some_var'] = 'This is what I want to show'
        return super(DuplicateTestCaseAdmin, self).changelist_view(request, extra_context=extra_context)

    def changelist_view(self, request, extra_context=None):
        extra_context = extra_context or {}
        try:
            p = int(request.GET.get('p', 1))
        except Exception as e:
            p = 1
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = AIAnalyzeForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                project = get_object_or_404(Project,
                                            pk=request.POST.get('project'))
                correct_jira_cred = False
                try:
                    jira = Jira(project.jiraapi.project_key, project.jiraapi.email,
                                project.jiraapi.api_token, project.jiraapi.jira_subdomain)
                    jira_data = jira.get_test_cases()
                    correct_jira_cred = True
                except Exception as e:
                    correct_jira_cred = False
                    messages.error(request, _(
                        "Please enter correct jira credentials for this project."))
                if correct_jira_cred:
                    duplicated_data = jira.get_test_cases_marked_as_duplicates()
                    filtered_jira_data = [
                        i for i in jira_data + duplicated_data if i not in jira_data or i not in duplicated_data]
                    extra_context['show_ai_result'] = True
                    threshold = form.cleaned_data.get('threshold')

                    ai_result = handle_json_ai_up(json.dumps(
                        filtered_jira_data), threshold.max, threshold.min)
                    folder = '%s/ai_models/user_%s/ai_results' % (
                        settings.BASE_DIR, request.user.id)
                    if not os.path.exists(folder):
                        os.makedirs(folder)
                    file = get_ai_result_file_name(
                        settings.BASE_DIR, request.user.id, project.id)

                    with open(file, 'wb') as fh:
                        pickle.dump(ai_result, fh)

                    return HttpResponseRedirect("%s/results/" % project.id)
                    translations = {
                        'sno': _('Sno.'),
                        # 'thres_score': _('Threshold score'),
                        'test_case_id': _('Test case id'),
                        'test_case_summary': _('Test case summary'),
                        'dup_test_case_ids': _('Duplicate test case id\'s'),
                        'action': _('Action'),
                        'action': _('Done'),
                    }
                    extra_context['json_data'] = ai_result
                    extra_context['translations'] = translations
                    extra_context['project'] = project.id
                    return super(DuplicateTestCaseAdmin, self).changelist_view(
                        request, extra_context=extra_context,
                    )
        form = AIAnalyzeForm()
        if request.user.is_superuser:
            projects = Project.objects.all()
        elif request.user.is_client_user():
            projects = Project.objects.filter(
                users=request.user.client.created_by)
        else:
            projects = Project.objects.filter(users=request.user)
        paginator = Paginator(projects, 20)
        page_obj = paginator.get_page(p)
        extra_context['form'] = form
        extra_context['projects'] = page_obj
        extra_context['paginator'] = page_obj
        return super(DuplicateTestCaseAdmin, self).changelist_view(request, extra_context=extra_context)


admin.site.register(Project, ProjectAdmin)
admin.site.register(DuplicateTestCase, DuplicateTestCaseAdmin)
admin.site.unregister(Task)
admin.site.unregister(CompletedTask)
```

Comment: if using users insted of added by i am getting error. (admin.E108) The value of 'list_display[2]' refers to 'added_by', which is not a callable, an attribute of 'ProjectAdmin', or an attribute or method on 'test_suite_optimizer.Project'. Can't i solve this issur be using added_by

Comment: This error in your `admin.py` file ,that contain `added_by` field but you remove this field in model. So you can change `added_by` field in all place you used.

Comment: posted admin.py

Comment: please change `added_by`  to  `users` in `admin.py`.

Comment: Are you migrate after change th model ??

Comment: django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1054, "Unknown column 'users_id' in 'field list'"). This is the error i am getting after that

Comment: NameError: name 'admin' is not defined. this error getting

Comment: please import `from django.contrib import admin`

Comment: while doing python manage.py migrate getting error. MySQLdb._exceptions.IntegrityError: (1062, "Duplicate entry 'project5-3' for key 'test_suite_optimizer_project_name_added_by_id_d8e02dc8_uniq'")

Comment: MySQL Strict Mode is not set for database connection 'default'

Comment: `users = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True, default=None,unique=True)` change this to `users = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True,unique=True)`

Comment: and i shouldnt add classs meta with unique_together

Comment: But in `users` field remove `default=None` in model.

Comment: Still while migrating i am getting error of mysql.connection.query(self, query)
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: (1062, "Duplicate entry 'project5-3' for key 'test_suite_optimizer_project_name_added_by_id_d8e02dc8_uniq'")

Comment: please remove this id (`1062`) row from `Project` table. Your table contain duplicated entry.

Comment: Hi it is working fine.... But when i create same project of same name it leads to integrityError at/admin/ instead it should give an error message on django admin that "this project already exists". can you help? How should i fix this??